# Pubnub : How to estimate history chat messages count prior to calling ngHistory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pubnub

I want to know whether we can retrieve count of history messages in pubnub channel prior to calling ngHistory. I am using Angularjs.

I need to show a loader until message history is loaded. Now , since pubnub is routing all history and chat typed to a single event, I need to hide the loader inside the event. But this makes a problem when there are no messages in history. The loader will not be hidden since the event has not been called at least once. If I put the code for hiding the spinner outside the event, it will immediately hide the loader long before the history is loaded. I have tried using callback for ngHistory but it was not triggered.

If I could retrieve count of messages, I can hide the loader if history message count is 0.

I use the below code:

```
$scope.limit = 50;
ActivityIndicator.showSpinner(); // to show a spinner

PubNub.ngHistory({
                    channel : $scope.channel,
                    limit   : $scope.limit
                    });

$rootScope.$on(PubNub.ngMsgEv($scope.channel), function(ngEvent, payload) {

            $scope.messages.push(payload.message);
            ActivityIndicator.hideSpinner(); // to hide the spinner

        });
```

The problem is when there are no messages, the event will not fire, if the event does not fire, hide spinner will never be called.

By default in pubnub, they are implemented like this. If they can ensure the event will be called at least once, then the issue will be solved. I looked into the pubnub Angularjs library, I could find out the following code routes messages to event:

```
c.ngHistory = function(args) {
        args.callback = c._ngFireMessages(args.channel); // to route messages to event
        return c.jsapi.history(args);
      };
```

If I comment the second line and implement a callback for ngHistory call like this:

```
PubNub.ngHistory({
                    channel : $scope.channel,
                    limit   : $scope.limit,
                    callback : function(payload){
                        $scope.messages.push(payload.message);
                       ActivityIndicator.hideSpinner(); // to hide the spinner
                            }

                    });
```

Then the code works fine. But since editing a library file is not recommended. I should not do that. Do you have any other idea to rectify this problem?

Comment: i did it myself. Created a new module and injected pubnub into it. In that module, i have overridden ngHistory by commenting the second line. This works fine for me.

Comment: Today there is no way to know but you can set the LIMIT to **cap** the max number of messages returned.

Answer (score 2):

## AngularJS PubNub SDK Determine Number of Messages to be Returned by `ngHistory()` Method

Today as of now, there is not a way to determine the number of messages in a channel.  However you can `limit` the max returned messages by using the `limit : 10` parameter in your `PubNub.ngHistory({ ... })` call.

Comment: There was a recent question answered on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241630/how-to-implement-callback-in-nghistory-in-pubnub