# How to implement callback in ngHistory in Pubnub?

Tags: angularjs, pubnub

When trying to retrieve the history message in the **on** event , the loading time is too long.
The spinner show and hides too fast. But the message is not  yet loaded.

How can we calculate or get the exact time to make the history load?

```
 $scope.limit = 100
 PubNub.ngHistory( {
                        channel : $scope.channel,
                        limit   : $scope.limit
                        });

   $rootScope.$on(PubNub.ngMsgEv($scope.channel), function(ngEvent, payload) {

                **ActivityIndicator.showSpinner();**

                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.messages.push(payload.message);
                });

                $(".messages-wrap").scrollTop($(".messages-wrap")[0].scrollHeight);
                **ActivityIndicator.hideSpinner();**

            });
```

Comment: should be instantly fast!

Comment: c.ngHistory = function(args) {
        args.callback = c._ngFireMessages(args.channel);
        return c.jsapi.history(args);
      };

Comment: The call back function in the library overrides the ngHistory custom call back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you so much for trying out the PubNub AngularJS API! I'll try
to provide some help. There is a little bit of a difference between
the PubNub JS API and the PubNub AngularJS API in this case.

**Background**

Behind the scenes, The PubNub JS API `history()` method returns instantly,
and invokes the callback when the given "page" of history is retrieved.

The AngularJS API, in its quest for simplifying this interaction, does not
take a callback - instead, it calls `$rootScope.$broadcast()` for each message
in the returned history payload.

In this version of the AngularJS API, it's not currently possible to "get inside"
the 'ngHistory' method to provide a callback. However, there are 2 solutions
available to you: one has always been there, and the second one I just added
based on your feedback.

**Solutions**

1) See codepen here (http://codepen.io/sunnygleason/pen/afqmh). There is an "escape hatch" in the PubNub AngularJS API that lets you call the JS API directly for advanced use cases, called `jsapi`. You can call `PubNub.jsapi.history({channel:theChannel,limit:theLimit,callback:theCallback})`. The only thing to keep in mind is that this will not fire message events into the $rootScope, and you will need to call `$rootScope.$apply()` or `$scope.$apply()` to make sure any changes you make to `$scope` within the callback function are propagated properly to the view.

2) See codepen here (http://codepen.io/sunnygleason/pen/JIsek). If you prefer a promise-based approach, I just added an `ngHistoryQ()` function to version 1.2.0-beta.4 of the PubNub AngularJS API. This will let you write code like:

```
PubNub.ngHistoryQ({channel:theChannel,limit:theLimit}).then(function(payload) {
  payload[0].forEach(function(message) {
    $scope.messages.push(message);
  }
});
```

You can install the latest version of the AngularJS SDK using 'bower install pubnub-angular'.

With either of these solutions, you should be able to display and hide your spinner
accordingly. The only difference is in #2, you'll want to write code like this:

```
var historyPromise = PubNub.ngHistoryQ({channel:theChannel,limit:theLimit});
showSpinner();
historyPromise.then(function(payload) {
  // process messages from payload[0] array
  hideSpinner();
});
```

Does this help? Let me know what you think. Thank you again so much for trying this out.

Comment: Thank you for your detail reply. as a quick fix , extended the ngHistory function and use customized callback by commenting off the in build callback ourproject.factory('PubNubService', function(PubNub) {

    var pubnub = PubNub;
    pubnub.ngHistory = function(args) {
       // args.callback = c._ngFireMessages(args.channel);
        return pubnub.jsapi.history(args);
      };
 return pubnub;

});

Comment: Ok, glad that works! Hopefully the 2 mechanisms listed above provide a more complete solution that doesn't involve privately changing the library!

Comment: Thank you very much for sorting this out. i will accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you programmatically turn the spinner on at history call time, and programmatically disable it at callback time?

Comment: ngHistory overrides callback method to route all history to an event by deafult. And the event will not fire if there are no history messages.